# How to generate checkboxes from List<MyObject> with <s:checkboxlist /> tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts-tags

I am following a tutorial to create multiple checkboxes using the `<s:checkboxlist>` tag.

The difference between my project and the tutorial is that it uses a `List<String>` to generate the checkbox list, while I have a `List<KMCountry>` (and need to generate the checkbox list from the textual value of an attribute of the `KMCountry` object).

**Action**

```
List<KMCountry> kmCountryListAll;

public List<KMCountry> getKmCountryListAll() {
    return kmCountryListAll;
}
```

**Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KM_COUNTRY")
public class KMCountry implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idCountry;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "workingHours")
    private String workingHours;

    // Getters and setters    
}
```

**JSP**

```xml
<s:checkboxlist label="Select Countries" 
                 list="kmCountryListAll" 
              listKey="idCountry" 
            listValue="name" 
                value="defaultCountry" />
```

But this way it doesn't work.

Using the debugger I see that it enters into the `getKmCountryListAll()` method and returns the `kmCountryListAll` list, but in the view I get the following error:

```
Expression parameters.name is undefined on line 38, column 32 in template/simple/checkboxlist.ftl.
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> ${parameters.name?html} [on line 38, column 30 in template/simple/checkboxlist.ftl]
 in user-directive s.iterator [on line 25, column 5 in template/simple/checkboxlist.ftl]
 in include "/${parameters.templateDir}/simple/checkboxlist.ftl" [on line 25, column 1 in template/css_xhtml/checkboxlist.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression parameters.name is undefined on line 38, column 32 in template/simple/checkboxlist.ftl.
    at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:124)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:118)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.StringBuiltins$StringBuiltIn._getAsTemplateModel(StringBuiltins.java:71)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:299)
    at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:130)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.include(Environment.java:1483)
    at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:169)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:190)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine.renderTemplate(FreemarkerTemplateEngine.java:157)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.mergeTemplate(UIBean.java:559)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:513)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at jsp_servlet._countryarea.__showmultiselectcountry._jsp__tag0(__showmultiselectcountry.java:107)
    at jsp_servlet._countryarea.__showmultiselectcountry._jspService(__showmultiselectcountry.java:70)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:526)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:157)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:277)
    at egp.prc.km.utils.interceptors.LiferayAjaxInterceptor.intercept(LiferayAjaxInterceptor.java:28)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:270)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.servlet.StrutsServlet.service(StrutsServlet.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
<17-mar-2015 14.57.09 CET> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@771696009[app:KM_Web_war_exploded module:KM-Web-1.0.0 path:/KMPortlets spec-version:2.5]] Servlet failed with Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendContentError(ServletResponseImpl.java:611)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:655)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:819)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:519)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Why? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `name` attribute to your `<s:checkboxlist>` tag

Comment: It's also worth noting that [the documentation is wrong](https://struts.apache.org/docs/checkboxlist.html), indicating the `name` attribute as not mandatory. Copy & paste probably.

Answer (score 1):

As the "Expression parameters.name is undefined on line 38, column 32 in template/simple/checkboxlist.ftl." says, you should add a NAME attribute to parameters bean or what ever parameter is.